# div with class will not recognize css styles

Tags: html, css

I created a new div and placed some stuff inside. I then went to the stylesheet and created the corresponding styles. When I go to refresh the page and inspect the element the div is not pulling the styles from the stylsheet. Help because its really frustrating.

here is the html

```
<div class="2columnlayout">
        <div id="managecontent1">
            <img src="img/wordpress-logo.png" />
            <p>Wordpress</p>
        </div>
        <div id="managecontent2">
            <img src="img/filezillaicon.png" />
            <p>F.T.P.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and here is the corresponding css that it won't recognize

```
.2columnlayout{
text-align: center;
font-size: 24px;
font-weight: 300;
margin-top: 90px;
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write like this:

```
.columnlayout2
```

instead of

```
.2columnlayout
```

because **CSS** is not recognized the `Class` & `ID` which start with numerical number.

Answer (score 0):

Classes may not start with a number. Rename it to something like `twocolumnlayout` instead.

Comment: thanks for telling me why. i didnt know that. feel stupid now haha:)

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
<div class="columnlayout">
        <div id="managecontent1">
            <img src="img/wordpress-logo.png" />
            <p>Wordpress</p>
        </div>
        <div id="managecontent2">
            <img src="img/filezillaicon.png" />
            <p>F.T.P.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Style sheet is:

```
.columnlayout div p{
text-align: center;
font-size: 24px;
font-weight: 300;
margin-top: 90px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [syntax rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#tokenization) of CSS disallow an identifier that starts with a digit, such as `2columnlayout`, so the selector in the rule is invalid and the entire rule is thus ignored.

As suggested in other answers, you can avoid this problem by using a class name that starts with a letter. This is usually best when applicable.

However, a class name may start with a digit (the restriction is in CSS syntax, not in HTML syntax), and if you *cannot* change the class name, you can use an [escape notation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters) for the digit. Here you could replace the digit `2` by `\32`  (backslash, digit three, digit two, space), an escape notation based on the Unicode code number (32 in in hexadecimal) of the digit:

```
.\32 columnlayout {
  /* declarations here */
}
```